# Creating a categorical label matrix

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm building a CNN for leaf recognition.

I'm using this dataset: [leafnsap dataset](http://leafsnap.com/dataset/)

As much as I have no problem loading the images and converting that to a np array and building the model with Keras.

I have some diffculties building the matrix of values.

This matrix should have this size: [number of images][number of labels]

And each [i][j] position equals to 1 if the image at position i has the same label as the labels matrix at position j. 
0 otherwise.

Here's what the txt(csv) file looks like: 
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11Ofh.png)

Here's some code:

```
#imports
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot  as plt
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
#loading and visualization of the data
path_to_txt = "D:\DevData\lato_project\leafsnap-dataset\leafsnap-dataset- 
images_improved.txt"
df = pd.read_csv(path_to_txt ,sep='\t')
arr = np.array(df)
print(arr.shape)
```

print: (30866, 4)

```
images = []
labels = []
for row in arr:
    if "lab" in row[0]:
        pass #nothing 
    else:
        if row[2] in labels:
            pass #nothing
        else:
            labels.append(row[2])
print(len(labels))
```

print: 181 (this is the number of different species)

```
#values is supposed to be a [7524][181] binary matrix for the training of the cnn
for row in arr:
    if "lab" in row[0]:
        pass
    else:
        img = cv2.imread("leafsnap-dataset/" + row[0])
        img = cv2.resize(img,(260,200))
        images.append(img)
values = np.zeros([len(imges), len(labels)])
```

At this point I can't find how to do that simple operation. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

for row in arr:
    if "lab" in row[0]:
        pass
    else:
        img = cv2.imread("leafsnap-dataset/" + row[0])
        img = cv2.resize(img,(260,200))
        images.append(img)
        labels.append([row[2]])

obj = OneHotEncoder()
values = obj.fit_transform(labels).toarray()
```

You can use `inverse_transform` method to get back the label from the encoding.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html